# Keep Xubuntu Network Manager from overwriting resolv.conf

Tags: network-manager

How do I keep Xubuntu 11.10 from overwriting `resolv.conf` everytime I reboot my machine?

Everytime I reboot, I get an overwritten `resolv.conf` that has the words `# Generated by Network Manager` and no nameservers specified.

I ran the following to get rid of Network Manager, but it's still replacing my resolv.conf when I restart the machine.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove network-manager
sudo apt-get --purge remove network-manager-gnome
sudo apt-get --purge remove network-manager-pptp
sudo apt-get --purge remove network-manager-pptp-gnome
```

Comment: Okay nevermind I changed the eth1 to eth0 and rebooted, this time it didn't overwrite my resolv.conf

*shrugs* 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can add this as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue you are trying to resolve?

I remember having had issues with `resolv.conf` on my Ubuntu 9.04/9.10-days. No nameserver was written into it and hence I had no Internet access.

As a solution I changed the starting order by renaming `/etc/rc.S/S07resolvconf` to `/etc/rc.S/S39resolvconf` and the problem went away.

It seems my solution was out of date, though the bug seems to be the same.

As mentioned at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/448095/comments/85) you could try `apt-get purge resolvconf`. Then you should be able to manually set your nameserver without it getting overwritten.

Comment: So just by changing the order in which the service starts up, I can avoid this?  Worth a shot I guess..

Comment: Hmm well I have rc4, rc5, etc...and none of them appear to have SXXresolvconf in them.  There's one that's pretty close called SXXdns-clean but that's about all...